# LibGDX implement leaderboard

Tags: libgdx, google-play, google-play-services, leaderboard

I am looking for leaderboard implementation in my app. I use libGDX and I found this guide: http://theinvader360.blogspot.it/2013/10/google-play-game-services-tutorial-example.html .

If I implement the same things of this guide I have an error with LeaderboardserviceAPI so I think it could be cause by the google play services changes. How could I implement leaderboard ?

Comment: If you are seeing an error, please edit your question and provide (1) the details of the error you are seeing (including the message and what triggers it at compile time? run time?) and (2) ideally provide a snippet of the relevant code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @P.T. I don't have any particular error. Google updated the Play Services so the guide I follow is deprecated. I can't use the ActionResolver Class because LeaderboardservicesAPI doesn't exist anymore

Comment: If you're asking for a better tutorial, StackOverflow is not the right place.  If you've tried using the Google Play Services API docs and have a specific question, please ask that.